# Custom post type single page returns 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called `slide`. It has content and some custom fields. I want **WP** to show the `single.php` theme or `single-slide.php` theme when the user clicks the slide single page link. the problem I have is that **WP** throws `404 error`, when I want to see the single slide page.

here is my code in `functions.php`:

```
function create_slide_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'افزودن', 'i2sa' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'افزودن اسلاید جدید', 'i2sa' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'اسلاید جدید', 'i2sa' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'ویرایش اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'نمایش اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'همه اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'جستجوی اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'اسلایدهای مادر:', 'i2sa' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'اسلایدی پیدا نشد.', 'i2sa' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'اسلایدی در زباله دان پیدا نشد.', 'i2sa' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => "اسلایدهای شرکت i2sa",
        'public'             => true,
        'exclude_from_search'=> true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => false,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'slide' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'slide', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to setting -> **Permalink** and update it.

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

the custom post type should be queryable from public so:

```
function create_slide_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'افزودن', 'i2sa' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'افزودن اسلاید جدید', 'i2sa' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'اسلاید جدید', 'i2sa' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'ویرایش اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'نمایش اسلاید', 'i2sa' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'همه اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'جستجوی اسلایدها', 'i2sa' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'اسلایدهای مادر:', 'i2sa' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'اسلایدی پیدا نشد.', 'i2sa' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'اسلایدی در زباله دان پیدا نشد.', 'i2sa' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => "اسلایدهای شرکت i2sa",
        'public'             => true,
        'exclude_from_search'=> true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,//here should be changed
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => false,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-images-alt2',
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'slide' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'slide', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for some plugins for the custom post type. The best plugin i can suggest you is the [Types](https://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) plugin.

Create Post Type, Custom Fields along with Taxonomies as much as you want without any problem.

It provides you every option as it is for default post type "POST".